# Yii2 ReflectionException Class yii\web\urlManager does not exist

Tags: php, yii2

I am building my website with Yii2 advanced template. The URL is rewritten into

```
localhost:9001/projectyii/page/index/#/demo
```

(`page` is controller, `index` is action, `/#/demo` is just a route for AngularJS on frontend)
Everything works fine on my localhost. When I upload it into my server, whenever if I hit the URL has prefix `example.com/projectyii/`, it will throw the following exception

**ReflectionException**

**Class yii\web\urlManager does not exist**

```
1. in /home/scott/public_html/projectyii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php at line 415
406407408409410411412413414415416417418419420421422423424     * @return array the dependencies of the specified class.
     */
    protected function getDependencies($class)
    {
        if (isset($this->_reflections[$class])) {
            return [$this->_reflections[$class], $this->_dependencies[$class]];
        }

        $dependencies = [];
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class); // error here
```

I notice that there are some other websites that have been running on same server already (they are all using Yii 1.1.13) and they have been working without problem, such as

```
example.com/project1/
example.com/project2/
```

...

it's just failed just this new site in Yii2.

The setting is under of components on `/frontend/config/main.php` is

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,

            'rules' => [],
        ]
```

The error told that it could not find the `urlManager` class, but the class does exist, the namespace is fine because I DO NOT modify anything on the vendors folder where contains that `urlManager` class.
I do not understand what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It should be `yii\web\UrlManager`

Comment: The case sensitive on Linux. That is why it worked on Windows (localhost) and didn't run on my server. How silly I am. Thank soju

Answer (score 0):

Linux like other unix systems are case sensitive you should use:

`'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',` instead of urlManager